# How to retry until success or timeout asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I wrote down these lines of code:

```
public static bool RetryUntilSuccessOrTimeoutAsync(Func<bool> task, 
TimeSpan executionTimeout, CancellationToken? token = null) {
        var data = new ExecutionContextData(task, executionTimeout, token);

        var nonBlockingTask = new Task<bool>(SyncTaskExecutor, data);
        nonBlockingTask.Start();

        var result = nonBlockingTask.ContinueWith(t => t.Result);
        return result.Result;
    }

class ExecutionContextData {
        private readonly Func<bool> task;
        private readonly TimeSpan executionTimeout;
        private readonly CancellationToken? cancellationToken;

        public ExecutionContextData(Func<bool> task, TimeSpan executionTimeout, CancellationToken? cancellationToken) {
            this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            this.executionTimeout = executionTimeout;
            this.task = task;
        }

        public Func<bool> Task {
            get { return task; }
        }

        public TimeSpan ExecutionTimeout {
            get { return executionTimeout; }
        }

        public CancellationToken? CancellationToken {
            get { return cancellationToken; }
        }
    }

private static bool SyncTaskExecutor(object executionHelper) {
        var context = executionHelper as ExecutionContextData;
        Task<bool> newTask = 
context.CancellationToken.HasValue ? new Task<bool>(ExecuteTask, context.Task, context.CancellationToken.Value) 
: new Task<bool>(ExecuteTask, context.Task);
        newTask.Start();

        bool timeoutResult = newTask.Wait(context.ExecutionTimeout);
        if (timeoutResult)
            return newTask.Result;
        return false;
    }
```

But as I understand the Result property invokation will block a caller. So, I quite don't understand how to accomplish this task:
"How to execute a task asynchronously, so if timeout is exceeded then it will return false or it will return the result of the task which should be executed over and over again?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try something like this if you have operations that you may want to cancel or have time out:

```
public static class Retries
{
    public enum Result
    {
        Success,
        Timeout, 
        Canceled,
    }

    public static Task<Result> RetryUntilTimedOutOrCanceled(this Func<bool> func, CancellationToken cancel, TimeSpan timeOut)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var end = start + timeOut;
            while (true)
            {
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                if (end < now)
                    return Result.Timeout;
                var curTimeOut = end - now;
                Task<bool> curTask = null;
                try
                {
                    if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return Result.Canceled;
                    curTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(func, cancel);
                    curTask.Wait((int)curTimeOut.TotalMilliseconds, cancel);
                    if (curTask.IsCanceled)
                        return Result.Canceled;
                    if (curTask.Result == true)
                        return Result.Success;
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    return Result.Timeout;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    return Result.Canceled;
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return Result.Canceled;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Func<bool> AllwaysFalse = () => false;
        Func<bool> AllwaysTrue = () => true;

        var result = AllwaysFalse.RetryUntilTimedOutOrCanceled(cancelSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        result = AllwaysTrue.RetryUntilTimedOutOrCanceled(cancelSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        var rTask = AllwaysFalse.RetryUntilTimedOutOrCanceled(cancelSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        cancelSource.Cancel();
        result = rTask.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```